# Adobe Animate stop working on Windows 10 1803 update

Tags: windows, jquery-animate, adobe, updates

After my PC auto update this morning Windows is now with version 1803 (April 2018 Update). When I try to start Adobe Animate CC 2018, app crashed after splash screen. App is trying to load, I can see for a second "Not Responding" in title bar and Animate process closed.
Anyone has the same problem?

I try old suggestions and delete C:\Users[MY_USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Adobe\Animate CC 2018 folder and C:\Users[MY_USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Animate folder, but the problem still exist.

UPDATE: Event Viewer pointed as problem C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll

UPDATE 2: Fresh and full installation of Windows didn't help. Problem is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! If you have the same problem - download old version of ucrtbase.dll (I use version 10.0.16299.248 File size: 1 002 592 bytes).
Login in safe mode and replace ucrtbase.dll from C:\Windows\System32\ with old one.